# HAProxy max out at ~10,700 connections

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy, load-testing, ejabberd

I am stress testing ejabberd with Tsung.  My EC2 instances setup as follows:

- Tsung : c3.xlarge
- ejabberd : c3.2xlarge
- HAProxy : t1.mirco

When I let Tsung talk to the ejabberd instance directly, I easily get my intended 35K+ connections within 5 mins.  When I throw HAProxy between the two of them, then I get ~10K max connections.  No HAProxy error logs, CPU runs 9%, Mem is 18% usage on the HAProxy instance.  The ulimit is set properly on the instance.  Is there perhaps something obviously that I am missing here?  Any advice most welcome.

My HAProxy config as follows:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 512000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    #timeout connect  5000
    #timeout client  10000
    #timeout server  10000
    timeout connect  5s
    timeout client  24h
    timeout server  24h

listen stats :80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth xx:xx


listen ejabberd_proxy :5222
    maxconn 512000
    mode    tcp
    retries 2
    option redispatch
    option tcplog
    option tcpka
    option clitcpka
    option srvtcpka
    balance leastconn
    server ejabberd1 ip_1:5222 check fall 10
    server ejabberd2 ip_2:5222 check fall 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a larger instance size for your haproxy node. t1.micro instances have **horrible** network and IO performance, and I wouldn't be surprised if one if those were causing the problem.

Comment: Will do a c3.xlarge instance type for the HAProxy instance quickly and see what goes.

Comment: It was exactly that!  Lesson learned:  stay away from EC2 t1.micro instances for this type of load testing.  I should have thought about that earlier seeing that I ended up with bigger instances for the Tsung and ejabberd boxes.  Thanks again for just pointing out the **horrible** nature of t1.micro for anything that needs a bit of power behind it.